# R: Reshape count matrix to long format with multiple entries

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a matrix. The entries of the matrix are counts for the combination of the dimension levels. For example:

```
(m0 <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2, dimnames=list(c("A","B"),c("A","B"))))
  A B
A 1 3
B 2 4
```

I can change it to a long format:

```
library("reshape")
(m1 <- melt(m0))
  X1 X2 value
1  A  A     1
2  B  A     2
3  A  B     3
4  B  B     4
```

But I would like to have multipe entries according to *value*:

```
m2 <- m1
for (i in 1:nrow(m1)) {
     j <- m1[i,"value"]
     k <- 2
     while ( k <= j) {
         m2 <- rbind(m2,m1[i,])
         k = k+1
     }
 }
> m2 <- subset(m2,select = - value)
> m2[order(m2$X1),]
   X1 X2
1   A  A
3   A  B
31  A  B
32  A  B
2   B  A
4   B  B
21  B  A
41  B  B
42  B  B
43  B  B
```

Is there a parameter in `melt` which considers to multiply the entries according to value? Or any other library which can perform this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do this with `base R`.  We convert the `dimnames` of 'm0' to a 'data.frame' with two columns using `expand.grid`, then replicate the rows of the dataset with the values in 'm0', `order` the rows and change the row names to `NULL` (if necessary).

```
d1 <- expand.grid(dimnames(m0))
d2 <- d1[rep(1:nrow(d1), c(m0)),]
res <- d2[order(d2$Var1),]
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#    Var1 Var2
#1     A    A
#2     A    B
#3     A    B
#4     A    B
#5     B    A
#6     B    A
#7     B    B
#8     B    B
#9     B    B
#10    B    B
```

---

Or with `melt`, we convert the 'm0' to 'long' format and then replicate the rows as before.

```
 library(reshape2)
 dM <- melt(m0)
 dM[rep(1:nrow(dM), dM$value),1:2]
```

As @Frank mentioned, we can also use `table` with `as.data.frame` to create 'dM'

```
 dM <- as.data.frame(as.table(m0))
```

Comment: In base R, we can get the same result as melt with `as.data.frame(as.table(m0))`, I think.